# Drupal 6.19, ubercart Module 6.x-2.4 - Duplicate email notifications

Tags: drupal, ubercart

When using Conditional actions with ubercart, both the customer and admin email notification are double up each time.  My payment is through DPS (NZ version or something similar to paypal).

I believe I have search all faq on ubercart.org and drupal.org, but with no luck.

I have try recreating the trigger actions, and disenabling the standards settings and they are still sending out twice.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [Duplicate order notification e-mail, and duplicate stock decrement](http://drupal.org/node/644538). I believe that your issue (or very closed) is being discussed there, with some proposed solutions.